# WhereHas not working, in Has Many Relationsip

Tags: laravel

Im try to using where to show data is_default=1 in relationship using whereHas like this code

```
$data = $this->user->with('profile', 'account')
            ->whereHas('account', function ($query) use ($id) {
                return $query->where('is_default', 1);
            })
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->first();
```

but my return still showing all data of account, even i set where is_default=1

how i can solved this problem, please help me

Comment: Did you try ->where('id', $id) before whereHas.

Comment: you would have to do the same exact filtering you are doing in `whereHas` for the `with(['account' => ...])` ... you are not constraining the eager loading at all ... `whereHas` and `with` are doing 2 completely different things

Comment: Delete eagar loading `with('account')` and again

Comment: thank for your answer, i've been solved this problem using 

$data = $this->user->with(['profile', 'account_default' => function ($q) use ($id) {
            $q->where('is_default', 1);
        }])
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->first();

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```php
$data = $this->user->with('profile')->where('id', $id)
         ->whereHas('account', function($q) use ($id){
              return $q->where('is_default', 1);
})->first();
```

Comment: thank for your answer this problem solved using

$data = $this->user->with(['profile', 'account_default' => function ($q) use ($id) {
            $q->where('is_default', 1);
        }])
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->first();

Answer (score 0):

I've been solved this problem using this code

```
$data = $this->user->with(['profile', 'account_default' => function ($q) use ($id) {
            $q->where('is_default', 1);
        }])
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->first();
```